# Which $n$th order differential equations have $n$ linearly independent solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In [these](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/examples/B9Lb.pdf) notes (p. 28), it is stated that differential equation $28$ is a second order ordinary differential equation *therefore* there are two linearly independent solutions.

Which is the largest set $X$ of differential equations such that

$$\text{differential equation }x \in X \Rightarrow x  \text{ is } n\text{th order and there are }n \text{ linearly independent solutions}?$$

I think that $X$ is quite likely to be a subset of all linear differential equations, but really I'm not sure. Ideally I'd be interested in a largest $X$, but I wouldn't mind is someone knew some fairly large subsets of $X$.

Comment: Did you ever find a good reference for this?

Comment: @user1537366 No, I didn't.

Comment: I asked a new question anyway: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089286/an-nth-order-ode-has-n-linearly-independent-solutions

Answer (score 2):

Equuation 28 has the form

> **(eq 1)** *c X'' + b X' + a X = K*

where *a, b, c, K* are functions on *x*:

*c=-h/ (2 pi 2 m)*

*b=0*

*a=U(x)*

*K=E*

Given two solutions *X*, *Y*, the function *Z = Y - X* verifies the linear equation :

> **(eq 2)** *c Z'' + b Z' + a Z = 0*

And inversely, given a solution *X* of (1), for any solution  *Z*  of (2), the function *Y = X + Z* is also a solution of (1).

So: **the solution space of (1) is a translation of the solution space of (2).**

---

(2) is a linear homogeneus equation and we can easily check that :

1. The addition of two any solutions is also a solution
2. The multiplication of a solution by a constant is also a solution

So : **The solution space of (1) is a vector space**

---

To check that the dimension is exactly 2, we transofrm the **2nd order differential equation** (2) to a **1st order differential equation system** by introducing *W = Z'*:

> **(eq 3)**
>
> *W ' = -b/c W - a/c Z*
>
> *Z ' = W*

In our case, this can be done since *c≠0*.

So we have a 2 dimension, 1st order differential equation system. Using the theorm of existence and unicity of ordinary differential equations, we have that :

**Given an initial evaluation point** *x*, **for any inital values** *(z_0, w_0)*, **there exists one, and only one, solution** *(Z,W)* **that verifies (3)**

So we can build a bijective, linear map :

R² → {solutions of (3)}

QED

Comment: Thanks. However, you seem to have just proven the case for $n=2$, not general $n$ (or, indeed, for other types of differential equation).