# What is the intuitive explanation of the uniqueness theorem of differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to understand the second law of Newton and to inspire my son to study physics. My maths are elementary and so I don't understand the intuitive explanation of this very important theorem by the wikipedia.

Could someone  explain why this theorem is well posed for a first order equation and is violated for higher than second derivatives, considering that I am a layman?

Comment: Can you please point out the reference to the wikipedia article you were reading?

Comment: @uniquesolution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem It is the wiki article on the Picard theorem

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089286/an-nth-order-ode-has-n-linearly-independent-solutions) deals with going from "First order ODE's have a 1 dimensional solution space" to "$n$th order ODE's have an $n$ dimensional solution space".

Comment: to get helpful answers you should definitely expand your question. it is unclear what exactly you are asking about, and you also seem to misunderstand the point of Picard's theorem

Comment: @Bananach what is the point of the theorem?

Comment: to show that, under some assumptions, unique solutions of ODE exist, no matter their order. indeed, a higher order ODE can be rewritten as a first-order ODE in higher dimensions. using this trick, the initial condition of the high -dimensional first-order ODE turns into an initial condition for all derivatives up to order-1 of the higher-order ODE