# When solving a secondary differential equation, how do you know the solution is as general as possible?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

However how do you know that having y= C.F + P.I gives you the most general solution to the diff. equation, can you prove such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but I'm assuming you're asking when we know we have the most general answer to a second order ODE. Well, the answer is that every $n$th order homogeneous ordinary differential equation will have **exactly** $n$ *linearly independent* solutions. ([Discusssion on this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089286/an-nth-order-ode-has-n-linearly-independent-solutions)) The inhomogeneous counterparts to these homogeneous solutions will have the same linearly independent solutions plus a particular solution specific to the problem. 
In short, for a second order ODE, if you have an equation of the form $$f(x,y,y',y'')=g(x) \ \mathbf{(1)}$$
Where the homogeneous solution, $y_H$ satisfies $$f(x,y,y',y'')=0$$
and is of the form $$y_H(x)=c_1y_1(x)+c_2y_2(x)$$
Where $y_1$ and $y_2$ are *linearly independent* functions, then the general solution is given by $$y_G(x)=y_H(x)+y_P(x)$$
where $y_P$ is some *particular* solution to **(1)**. This will encapsulate every possible solution of **(1)**.